# Connecting 2 Java Me applications- One launching the another

Tags: java-me, mobile, midlet, cldc

Is there a way to launch one Java ME Midlet from another? Both of them would be running on CLDC Phones. What we are planning is that there's one main midlet that will do maximum of the work and there's a smaller midlet which will be launched based on certain condition in the main midlet.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically launching MIDlets is typically done using the MIDP2.x [PushRegistry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/) API (with a loopback network trigger) or using the [Content-Handling API](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=211) on the phones that support it (recent Samsung, Sony-Ericsson, Nokia...)